# PostgreSQL returning rows that no longer exist and does not return new entries

Tags: database, postgresql, express

I am running my application on OpenNebula cloud. I have a PostgreSQL database set up and it seems to be working fine, the rows are updated, new ones are added from data collection scripts, but when I access the database from the backend, it keeps on returning old rows, that have been deleted a week ago, and nothing more, nothing less, as if it was cached. I tried disabling cache on the backend (Express.js), as well as VACUUMing the database. Is it an issue with the PostgreSQL database setup or Backend setup?

This is my endpoint in express.js:

```
app.get('/getEntries', async (req, res) => {
    const client = await dbPool.connect();
    try {
        const pageSize = 10;
        const pageNumber = req.query.page || 1;
        const offset = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private');

        const result = await dbPool.query('SELECT * FROM listings');
        res.json(result.rows);

    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error fetching data');
    } finally {
        client.release();
    }
});
```

I can provide needed information and update the topic as much as needed.

I am connecting to the same database, the connection details have been checked.

When executing the same query directly on the database, the results returned are new ones, the old ones are not existing.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache on your browser?

Comment: @mitiko Browser, Postman, Express.js, everywhere I cleared or disabled cache.

Comment: Very long running transactions could lead to new rows no being visible, or "deleted" rows still being visible (because not committed, yet, or because still seeing an old snapshot). Transactions running for a week would be a problem in any case. You can check with `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity` ...

Comment: Given the long duration, my first guess would be a switcheroo with a stale instance of the same database. Do you have multiple instances? A copy for tests, maybe?

Comment: I have only one instance of database, there were no IDLE processes, only DBeaver one. As a matter of fact, when Database is accessed in DBeaver, it only shows new and valid data, whilst the backend keeps returning old one.